# Qt. Is there any way to put dots between label and value?

Tags: qt, tree, formatting

I have a set of values that are connected with their labels by dots. Is there any way to do it in Qt except manual input?

- Dots in a tree

[image: dots in a tree]

- Dots in a list

[image: dots in a list]

Comment: What widget are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderVX. No - please read the docs for [QFontMetrics.elidedText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText). It does not do what the OP is asking for at all.

Comment: Ok. I was wrong about eliding. IMHO somewhat similar to eliding method can be used but that needs overloading QLabel.

Comment: I also suggest use the QFontMetrics to get the size of the text elements and calculate the amount of needed points by yourself ;) That is maybe not the cleanest way, but it should work.